# How to grab number after word in python

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have a huge file containing the following lines `DDD-1126N|refseq:NP_285726|uniprotkb:P00112` and `DDD-1081N|uniprotkb:P12121`, I want to grab the number after `uniprotkb`.

Here's my code:

```
x = 'uniprotkb:P'
f = open('m.txt')
for line in f:
  print line.find(x) 
  print line[36:31 + len(x)]
```

The problem in `line.find(x)` is 10 and 26, I grab the complete number when it is 26. I'm new to programming, so I'm looking for something to grab the complete number after the word.

```
x = 'uniprotkb:'
f = open('m.txt')
for line in f:
  if x in line:
    print the number after x
```

Comment: You've still not accepted answers to most of your questions. You realize you get +2 reputation for each one you accept? You should mark the best / most helpful answer to each as accepted by clicking the check mark next to it, if at least one of the answers did help.

Answer (score 27):

Use regular expressions:

```
import re
for line in open('m.txt'):
    match = re.search('uniprotkb:P(\d+)', line)
    if match:
        print match.group(1)
```

Answer (score 9):

```
import re
regex = re.compile('uniprotkb:P([0-9]*)')
print regex.findall(string)
```

Comment: Note that this prints a list of everything that matches the regex

Answer (score 5):

The `re` module is quite unnecessary here **if** `x` is static and always matches a substring at the end of each line (like `"DDD-1126N|refseq:NP_285726|uniprotkb:P00112"`):

```
x = 'uniprotkb:'
f = open('m.txt')
for line in f:
  if x in line:
    print line[line.find(x)+len(x):]
```

---

**Edit:**
To answer you comment.  If they are separated by the pipe character (`|`), then you could do this:

```
sep = "|"
x = 'uniprotkb:'
f = open('m.txt')
for line in f:
  if x in line:
    matches = [l[l.find(x)+len(x):] for l in line.split(sep) if l[l.find(x)+len(x):]]
    print matches
```

If m.txt has the following line:

```
DDD-1126N|uniprotkb:285726|uniprotkb:P00112
```

Then the above will output:

```
['285726', 'P00112']
```

Replace `sep = "|"` with whatever the column separator would be.

Answer (score 1):

Um, for one thing I'd suggest you use the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) to read a TSV file.

But generally, you can use a regular expression:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r"(?<=\buniprotkb:)\w+")
for line in f:
    match = regex.search(line)
    if match: 
        print match.group()
```

The regular expression matches a string of alphanumeric characters if it's preceded by `uniprotkb:`.